# Run process in background of shell for 2 minutes, then terminate it before 2 minutes is up BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using Peppermint distro. I'm new to linux, however  I need to display system processes, then create a new process to run in the background for 2 minutes, I need to prove its running and then terminate it before the 2 minutes is up.

So far i'm using xlogo to test my process is working. I have

```
ps 
xlogo &
TASK_PID=$!

if pgrep -x xlogo>/dev/null 2>&1
then 
ps 
sleep 15
kill $TASK_PID

ps

fi
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to give it an initial time of 2 minutes but then kill it after 15 seconds anyway.

any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the `timeout` command?

Comment: @EricRenouf yea, first I was trying to xlogo & sleep 120 then timeout 15s, and couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the command to originally have a time limit of 2 minutes you could do

```
timeout 2m xlogo &
```

of course, then your `$!` will be of the `timeout` command.  If you're using `pgrep` and satisfied it's only finding the process you care about though, you could use `pkill` instead of the PID to kill the `xlogo`

Of course, killing the `timeout` PID will also kill `xlogo`, so you might be able to keep things as-is for the rest if you're happy with how that works.